# Regex confusing behavior when using \g modifier

Tags: regex

I'm fairly experienced in using regex, but I've come across something recently that I can't explain.

I was trying to make a regex that would match the `test` in both: `2015_test_1_2` and `test_1_2`. I came up with `/(?!\d)([^_]+)/` which worked when I tested each string individually; however, when I tested both at the same time, using the `/gm` modifier the `2015` from the first test matches if it isn't on the first line.

On the first line:

[image]

On the second line:

[image]

The example explains it better than I can: https://regex101.com/r/zF0iR5/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `[^_]` also matches a newline.

Either move last example text to first line or change your regex to:

```
(?!\d)([^_\n]+)
```

Or else:

```
(?![\d\n])([^_]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zF0iR5/7)

Comment: Thank you! I have one question though. Even if it does match a newline why doesn't the negative lookaround stop the numbers from matching?

Comment: Because next character is `\n` and negative lookahead `(?!\d)` succeeds there

Comment: So you can fix this regex by using `(?![\d\n])([^_]+)` also.

Comment: `(?!\d)([^_]+?)` solves it too :D. Thank you for your help. I'll accept in a minute.